# ASP Web App Timing Out Erratically

Tags: session, asp-classic

I am going to be working on an ASP web application for a client.  They are having problems with sessions timing out after periods of time ranging from 5 minutes to 4 hours after logging in.

Is there any known issues I should check to try to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe certain pages are adjusting the Timeout?
 Look for... `Server.ScriptTimeout = x` where x is the number of seconds before timeout.

I think the only other place to change Timeout is in IIS.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2275a2ba-5b12-4e18-8266-8a3b0678e419.mspx?mfr=true.

Good luck.